# What is the device at 0x68 on I2C2 of Google Coral?

Tags: i2c, google-coral, real-time-clock

I am trying to connect an external RTC (addr 0x68, on Witty Pi 3) to my Google Coral dev board on I2C2 (bus 1). But `i2cdetect` shows a device at 0x68 even without my external RTC connected. I can't find anything in the docs (SOM or dev board) about a device on this bus. Lady Ada at Adafruit has found it also https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-on-google-coral-linux-blinka?view=all#check-uart-i2c-and-spi-3027971-20 .

Does anyone know about this? Could point me at a doc?

Comment: Have you tried to ask Google (presumably on their public forums)?

Answer (score 0):

I went to google support:
"0x68 is the oscillator for PCIe, I believe it needed for communication with the EdgeTPU, therefore it should not be disabled."

So Witty Pi 3 is a non-starter. I'm lucky there's a Witty Pi 4.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).